# localStorage persisting key as object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to persit a ng-model as a key and trying to retrive, but its not working when its an object but working when ng-model is string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.7" data- semver="1.5.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>        
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <input type="text" ng- model="someText.something.firstName" persist="" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunkr here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/QQAxrOjsRzpK6u81J95J?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This question has a great explanation: [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

The short answer is that you will need to stringify any objects you want to store in localStorage, but be aware that there are some caveats to stringifying JS objects.

```
scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
  localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel is correct in that you must stringify objects, you also need to keep in mind that you can't have any circular references and that there IS a limit on how much stuff you can dump into localStorage. Due to that limit it's also a good idea to have a system in place to keep track of which items should be pushed out of cache and to actually invalidate them.